# What's a good site to see bid/ask walls?

Tags: exchange-rate

I'm currently using [Mtgoxlive](http://mtgoxlive.com/) to view ask and bid walls.

[image]

But ... I can't see the chart beyond about $1.5 +- the current price.

Is there another site for viewing ask/bid walls graphically, in a similar fashion to Mtgoxlive, that is limiting in the displayed data?

Also, a nice to have would be historic wall data. There is the [Wall Observer Thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=85687.0) ... is there another site that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[btccharts.com](http://btccharts.com) is a better version of mtgoxlive.com - it lets you zoom out to see more price range, and has a bunch of other features.

See [its forum thread](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=55385) for discussion of it.

Note: the site is currently [down for maintenance](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=55385.msg1019423#msg1019423) but should be back soon.

Also, [clarkmoody](http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/) will show you a live updating view of the market, but the depth is shown numerically, not on a graph.